# I would like to center a table when the media is under 980px. I tried margin and text-align. They are not working

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like to build my website with responsive design concept. but I already tried `margin: 0 auto` and `text-align: center`. Both can't be help to center the table. I already try to disable some style that may affect the element such as `right: 30px/ float: right` in the chrome developer tool. but I still can't find the reason.

My website is on http://php-kkhchan.rhcloud.com
I would like to center the table which is on the top. All my responsive design setting is depend on CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #searchBox, #tab, #weaExp, #weaAud, .desktop, svg {
        display: none;
    }

    #tblhead {
        float: left;
        right: auto; //it is to override the style from normal view
        margin-left: 30px; //since I am unable to set it to center. I now only to set it align to left.
    }
}
```

The below is part of my html code:

```
<body text="#000000">
<table id="tblhead"><TR>
<TD style="width:145px;"><?php include("login.php") ?></TD>
<TD><span style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"> | </span></TD>
<TD><a id="fb_qr" href="lib/qr.htm"><span id="myQR" class="myButton" tabindex="4">QR</span></a></TD>
<TD><span style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"> | </span></TD>
<TD><a id="fb_map" href="lib/map.htm"><span id="myMap"  class="myButton" tabindex="4">Map</span></a></TD>
<TD><span style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"> | </span></TD>
<TD><a id="fb_mo" href="/mobile/index.php"><span id="ver"  class="myButton" tabindex="4">Mobile</span></a></TD>
<TD><span style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"> | </span></TD>
<TD><span id='weaBox'><p id='weaTmp'></p></span></TD>
<TD><span style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"> | </span></TD>
<TD><article id="clkBox"><span id="clkText" onClick="clkChgColor();"></span></article></TD>
</TR></table>
```

by the way, I tried to add the below statement so that the screen layout like a mobile. but I wonder why the result is that the zoom will be very high. 1/3 of content was exceed the boundary and can't be view.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Can you add your `html` codes?

Comment: Added in the post.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, use a validator: https://validator.w3.org/nu/ (and don't use tables for layout, we have CSS now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#tblhead` element uses `position: fixed`, so you can't center it using `margin: auto`. You can use this trick to center it:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #tblhead {
        right: auto;
        left: 50%; /** left should 50% of parent - body because of fixed **/
        transform: translateX(-50%); /** move it back -50% of element itself **/
    }
}
```

Comment: It seem when the screen is very small. It will not be center.

Comment: I use this way, too... problem come when screen width is lower then table width, of course, if width is defined... +1

Comment: Remove the `margin-left: 30px;`, and it will be centered perfectly. Updated the answer to reflect the end result.

Comment: yes, I found that it will be perfectly on center. I already upload your solution on my website.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the css properties of the #tabs div.

```
#tabs {
    background: none !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: none;
    width: 900px;
    /* margin-left: 10px; */
    margin-left: 25%;
    /* position: fixed; */
    top: 10%;}
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But when the screen is not exactly 980px. The div will not be center.

Comment: Then write width as 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of `margin-left` and [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

If `#tblhead` width is 900px

> `margin-left: calc(50% - 450px)`

By using half of the width of `#tblhead`'s container and subtracting half the width of `#tblhead`, `#tblhead` will always be horizontally centered. When using `calc` it's **important to remember** to leave space around the minus `-` (or plus `+`, asterisk `*`, etc).

> Ex. Do this: `calc(50% / 2)`, do not do this: <del>`calc(50%/2)`</del>.

**SNIPPET**

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.45 'Verdana';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em;
}
#tblhead {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px 0;
  /* This is an important rule */
  margin-left: calc(50% - 450px); 
}
th {
  width: 32%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}
td {
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px inset #bbb;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #tblhead {
    width: 520px;
    /* This is an important rule */
    margin-left: calc(50% - 260px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta char="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="box">
    <table id="tblhead">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>HEAD</th>
          <th>HEAD</th>
          <th>HEAD</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```